# Hide 3 icons having 3 different class with CSS

Tags: css

I need to *hide* 3 icons in a page where I don't have access to html but where I can modify CSS file.

The **html** code is:

```
 <img class="color_box" title="Annotations" src="http://www.site.com/images/notice.png">

 <span class="with_tooltip" title="This is a message"></span>

 <img class="color_box with_tooltip" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" src="images/clear.gif" title="White">
```

I tried different combination such as :

```
.color_box with_tooltip{
    display:none;
}
```

or

```
.color_box, .with_tooltip{
     display:none;
}
```

but none of them allow to hide all icons. Some are hidden and some others no according how I change my code..

Any suggestions please ?

Comment: one sugestion, wrap everything in a <div> and display none in the div.

Comment: Your second CSS should have worked, unless there's a more specific rule elsewhere, or an equally specific rule later in the CSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS rules are applied via a specificity level. Rules that are more specific can trump those that are less specific.

So you may have a style like

```
#id .yourClass {something...}
```

That is trumping your `.yourClass` declaration alone.

A way around this is to use the `!important` flag. Try this:

.color_box, .with_tooltip {display:none !important;}

!important is typical a 'last resort' as it can make future CSS updates a pain, but the one place it is useful is when you have to modify an existing site via CSS only and simply have to strong arm some of your changes.

Comment: yes of course... Important flag solved the problem. Many thank

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the !important attribute to your second selector listed above. It could be that there are other styles in place that are overriding the hiding.

I created a very simple [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5qDAn/1/) that has this working without using the !important clause. You can remove the CSS and add it again to see it in action:

```
.color_box, .with_tooltip {display: none !important;}
```